# Every derived table must have its own alias? How is this wrong

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I've given my derived table an alias but still when i run the query it gives me the error "Every derived table must have its own alias".

```
select a,b,c,sum(d) as 'sum'
from(select a,b,c,sum(d)as 'd' from e join f using(z)) as 'alias'
group by a;


EDIT: better sample
----This gives derived table error-----
select name,sum(pop) as 'total' from(select name as 'name',sum(population) 
as pop from table1 join table2 using(countrycode));

----This gives me the SQL syntax error--------
select name,sum(pop) as 'total' from(select name as 'name',sum(population) 
as pop from table1 join table2 using(countrycode)) as 'alias';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not a valid MySQL query....

Comment: Could you try to come up with a [mcve] - e.g. a simple schema definition that lets people reproduce the error? The current code is so anonymized it's impossible to tell where your problem might be.

Comment: @IMSoP done sir.

Comment: @Supremo To be reproducible, we would need the `CREATE TABLE` statements, and if necessary some `INSERT`s. The ideal is that someone could copy the code from your question into an empty database, and see the error. Then they could test their suggestions against that same data, and know they worked.

Comment: Also, your latest edit mentions two different errors, but doesn't give the exact text of either of them. Again, to help people help you, you should give them all the details you know. Remember we're not looking over your shoulder, and things that are obvious to you because you've been staring at them for half an hour won't be obvious to us unless you tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
select name,
       sum(pop) as `total` 
from( 
        select name as `name`, sum(population) as pop 
        from table1 
        join table2 using(countrycode)
) `m` <---- alias needed here too
```